# Laravel 5.1 Repopulate Form from redirect()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

It doesn't work when I use redirect()

Its work:

```
//controller

$v = \Validator::make($request->all(), $this->form_rules);
        if ($v->fails()) {
            $request->flash();
            return view('user.form')->withErrors($v->errors())
                                    ->withInput($request->except("password"));
        }

//view

{!! Form::email('email', old('email') ) !!}
```

but I need to use redirect(), something like:

```
$v = \Validator::make($request->all(), $this->form_rules);
        if ($v->fails()) {
            $request->flash();
            return redirect('users/create')->withErrors($v->errors())
                                         ->withInput($request->except("password"));
        }
```

Comment: What does the controller handler method for your `users/create` route look like?

Comment: can you show us the error message that you get when you redirect ?

Comment: there is not error, it just dont do the repopulation

Comment: I don't have problems with the route or something like that 'users/create' is the right url 'user.form' is the view (blade)

Comment: @MiharbiHernandez I'm not questioning that. The code you have to supply the old input to the redirect is correct. However, you're saying it isn't working so we need to see the code that happens between the time you redirect and the time you try to use the old input. This is why I asked to see what you're doing in your handler method for the `users/create` route.

Comment: Did you try `->withInput()`?

Comment: @user2094178 yes, there is in my question "->withInput($request->except("password"))"

Comment: @MiharbiHernandez I think he wanted you to try `withInput()` without the parameter. However, that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Redirect and do `dd(Input::old())`, if it is not blank, then do `->withInput(Input::old())`, I had some problem similar once.

Comment: @user2094178 it is always null in the view, just calling the view  view('user.form') its works

Comment: @MiharbiHernandez I'm guessing you're doing a `$request->flash()` inside your `users/create` route before returning the view, which would cause your issue. But you haven't shown that code yet, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
return redirect('users/create')->withErrors($v->errors())
                                     ->withInput($request->except("password"));
```

to

```
return redirect('user/create')->withErrors($v->errors())
                                     ->withInput($request->except("password"));
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have problems with the route or something like that 'users/create' is the right url 'user.form' is the view (blade)